# Сравнение между традиционным Oracle и ANSI JOIN синтаксисами для соединения таблиц в запросе

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Не так давно я видел комментарии к вопросам включающих соединение таблиц в запросе: "Не пользуйтесь (+), лучше замените на JOIN синтаксис".

Как вижу, оба способа выполняют задачу. Но какая действительно разница в их использовании и когда надо пользоваться каким-то из них?

1. Есть ли какие-то ограничения при использовании их в приложениях, в производительности и т.п.?
2. Что предпочтительней использовать?

Я читал [документацию](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2080416), но не могу с уверенностью сказать, что я полностью разобрался с всеобъемлющей информацией.

Я обдумываю переписать около 200 пакетов и процедур, если лучше заменить (+) на явный JOIN.

Примеры запросов:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ INNER JOIN - CONVENTIONAL         │ INNER JOIN - ANSI SYNTAX                    │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT                            │ SELECT                                      │
│      emp.deptno                   │       ename,                                │
│ FROM                              │       dname,                                │
│      emp,                         │       emp.deptno,                           │
│      dept                         │       dept.deptno                           │
│ WHERE                             │ FROM                                        │
│      emp.deptno = dept.deptno;    │       scott.emp INNER JOIN scott.dept       │
│                                   │       ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;          │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ LEFT OUTER JOIN - CONVENTIONAL    │ LEFT OUTER JOIN - ANSI SYNTAX               │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT                            │ SELECT                                      │
│      emp.deptno                   │      ename,                                 │
│ FROM                              │      dname,                                 │
│      emp,                         │      emp.deptno,                            │
│      dept                         │      dept.deptno                            │
│ WHERE                             │ FROM                                        │
│      emp.deptno = dept.deptno(+); │      scott.emp LEFT OUTER JOIN scott.dept   │
│                                   │      ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;           │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ RIGHT OUTER JOIN - CONVENTIONAL   │ RIGHT OUTER JOIN - ANSI SYNTAX              │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT                            │ SELECT                                      │
│      emp.deptno                   │      ename,                                 │
│ FROM                              │      dname,                                 │
│      emp,                         │      emp.deptno,                            │
│      dept                         │      dept.deptno                            │
│ WHERE                             │ FROM                                        │
│      emp.deptno(+) = dept.deptno; │      scott.emp RIGHT OUTER JOIN scott.dept  │
│                                   │      ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;           │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ FULL OUTER JOIN - CONVENTIONAL    │ FULL OUTER JOIN - ANSI SYNTAX               │
├───────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ SELECT                            │ SELECT                                      │
│      *                            │      *                                      │
│ FROM                              │ FROM                                        │
│      emp,                         │      scott.emp FULL OUTER JOIN scott.dept   │
│      dept                         │      ON emp.deptno = dept.deptno;           │
│ WHERE                             │                                             │
│      emp.deptno = dept.deptno(+)  │                                             │
│ UNION ALL                         │                                             │
│ SELECT                            │                                             │
│      *                            │                                             │
│ FROM                              │                                             │
│      emp,                         │                                             │
│      dept                         │                                             │
│ WHERE                             │                                             │
│      emp.deptno(+) = dept.deptno  │                                             │
│      AND emp.deptno IS NULL;      │                                             │
└───────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/18891148/6571020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Подведу итог ответов и комментариев к ним**

1. Используйте новый ANSI JOIN синтаксис, чем традиционный синтаксис в `WHERE` клаузе, независимо от того, это `OUTER JOIN` или нет. Ведь так просто, по невнимательности, получить декартово произведение с традиционным, старым синтаксисом. Чем больше таблиц участвуют в соединении, тем больше риск пропустить по ошибке какое-то условие в соединении.
2. В общем, оператор `(+)` имеет массу ограничений по сравнению с ANSI JOIN. Кроме того, он доступен только в *Oracle*, когда ANSI JOIN синтаксис поддерживается всеми основными реляционными СУБД.
3. SQL не станет производительней после перехода на ANSI JOIN - это только различный синтаксис.
4. *Oracle* настоятельно рекомендует использовать более гибкий ANSI синтаксис в `FROM` клаузе. В прошлом были известны некоторые ошибки при использовании ANSI синтаксиса, но они уже были исправлены патчами в 11.2 и 12.1. Например, ошибка с JOIN в 12c смотри [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686262/query-featuring-outer-joins-behaves-differently-in-oracle-12c).
5. Использование JOIN операторов делает SQL код совместимым со стандартом, и это упростит при необходимости переход приложений на другие платформы БД.
6. Условия соединения имеют очень низкую селективность на каждую таблицу в соединении, но высокую селективность на кортежи в теоретическом декартовом произведении. Условия в WHERE обычно имеют более высокую селективность.
7. *Oracle* может неявно конвертировать ANSI синтаксис в `(+)` форму, что можно заметить в плане выполнения в секции с предикатами.

Источник: [@SriniV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114087/6571020).