# Что такое (+) в SQL запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть работающий SQL запрос, среди прочего в `where` части есть следующие строки:

```
and d.parent_id (+) = o.book_id 
and d.pax_number (+) = o.pax_number
```

Что это за `(+)`?

Comment: тип соединения , LEFT/RIGHT JOIN , зависит с какой стороны плюсик

Comment: А причём здесь он, если это фильтрация, а не условие соединения? Не понимаю=(

Comment: старый синтаксис, join через where

Comment: А, кажется дошло, т.е. это типа left join? А right был бы если and d.pax_number  = (+)o.pax_number?

Comment: `right join` будет `pax_number = o.pax_number (+)`

Answer (score 7):

Оператор `(+)` это старый синтаксис для внешнего соединения таблиц в SQL диалекте Oracle с условием соединения в предикате `WHERE`.

Он не входит в ANSI/ISO SQL стандарт, поддерживается незначительным количеством диалектов SQL (например, DB2) и не рекомендуется больше к использованию.

В вопросе не хватает основной части этого синтаксиса, таблиц разделённых `,` (запятой):

```sql
select ...
from tab1 d, tab2 o 
where ...
and d.parent_id (+) = o.book_id 
and d.pax_number (+) = o.pax_number
```

В старом синтаксисе нет эквивалентов ANSI синтаксиса: правое, левое или полное внешнее соединение (`left`, `rigth`, `full outer join`). Оператор `(+)` отмечает таблицу (в примере с алиасом `d`) как "необязательную" для внешнего соединения, независимо, стоит она справа или слева в условии соединения.

При невыполнении условия внешнего соединения, все значения столбцов из таблицы отмеченной оператором `(+)` в результирующем наборе записей будут `NULL` (неопределённы).

Подробное сравнение нового ANSI `JOIN` синтаксиса со старым в предикате `WHERE`, [в этой теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1007560/217579).

Answer (score 1):

Плюс, например, ставится на случай нулевых показателей в периоде, чтобы строка не удалялась. Т.е. в Марте не было события, которое есть в Январе, Феврале, Апреле... то из-за Марта эта строка с результатами пропала бы, и все данные по этой строке исключились бы из итогов. А так система понимает, что там NULL благодаря (+). (+) это значит покажи всё остальное в строке по этой части (левой или правой) даже если она NULL..

```
SELECT X.login, JAN.entr Январь, FEB.entr Февраль, MAR.entr Март, 
                APR.entr Апрель, MAY.entr Май, JUN.entr Июнь, JUL.entr Июль, 
                AUG.entr Август, SEP.entr Сентябрь, OCT.entr Октябрь, NOV.entr Ноябрь
           FROM X, JAN, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV
          WHERE X.login  = JAN.login (+) 
            AND X.login  = FEB.login (+)
            AND X.login  = MAR.login (+)
            AND X.login  = APR.login (+)
            AND X.login  = MAY.login (+)
            AND X.login  = JUN.login (+)
            AND X.login  = JUL.login (+)
            AND X.login  = AUG.login (+)
            AND X.login  = SEP.login (+)
            AND X.login  = OCT.login (+)
            AND X.login  = NOV.login (+)
       ORDER BY X.login;
```

По существу вопроса:

```
and d.parent_id (+) = o.book_id 
and d.pax_number (+) = o.pax_number
```

Здесь будут показаны даже те o.book_id и o.pax_number где d.parent_id и d.pax_number пустые

Comment: интересно, а я делал union к массиву чтоб пропуски нарисовались. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1013051/16574

Comment: так же красивее и в будущем пригодится :)