# Статистика по дням POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate

Если выполнить запрос к таблице с `... GROUP BY (date_trunc('day'::text, lower(accounting."time")))` то не выводятся дни в которых не было данных. Не удобно по таким данным рисовать графики.

```
SELECT sum(accounting.download)                          AS download,
       sum(accounting.upload)                            AS upload,
       date_trunc('day'::text, lower(accounting."time")) AS day
FROM accounting
WHERE 
       (lower(accounting."time") >= date_trunc('day'::text, (CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval))))
GROUP BY (date_trunc('day'::text, lower(accounting."time")))
ORDER BY (date_trunc('day'::text, lower(accounting."time")));
```

Хочу получить последовательность из дней в определенном диапазоне `[(CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval), CURRENT_DATE ]`, юнионом прицепить к основной таблице и тогда у меня будут начальные нули для агрегации.

Но как получить такой календарик?

```
generate_series((CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval), CURRENT_DATE, interval '1 day')
```

А есть ли по нему агрегация, чтоб не засовывать его под юнион?

Comment: *юнионом прицепить к основной таблице* Юнион-то с какого перепугу? простой `серия LEFT JOIN данные`.

Comment: Как я нули (0, not null) получу с жойном?

Comment: COALESCE() вокруг SUM()

Comment: @Akina получилось, разницы в скорости вроде нет на 30к строк. Добавьте ответ, я вставлю туда запрос с join

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

```
SELECT sum(r.download) AS download,
       sum(r.upload)   AS upload,
       r.day
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('day'::text, lower(accounting."time")) AS day,
             accounting.download,
             accounting.upload
      FROM accounting
      WHERE
             (lower(accounting."time") >= date_trunc('day'::text, (CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval))))
      UNION
      SELECT date_trunc('day'::text, "time"."time") AS day,
             0                                      AS download,
             0                                      AS upload
      FROM generate_series((CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval), (CURRENT_DATE)::timestamp without time zone,
                           '1 day'::interval) "time"("time")) r
GROUP BY r.day
ORDER BY r.day;
```

Можно как то улучшить?

По советам @Akina

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(r.download), (0)::numeric) AS download,
       COALESCE(sum(r.upload), (0)::numeric)   AS upload,
       r.day
FROM (SELECT date_trunc('day'::text, series."time") AS day,
             accounting.download,
             accounting.upload
      FROM (generate_series((CURRENT_DATE - '1 mon'::interval), (CURRENT_DATE)::timestamp without time zone,
                            '1 day'::interval) series ("time")
               LEFT JOIN accounting ON ((date_trunc('day'::text, lower(accounting."time")) =
                                                date_trunc('day'::text, series."time"))))) r
GROUP BY r.day
ORDER BY r.day;
```