# Перенос (+) из oracle в postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
   select
    app.SUID,
    app.CODE,
    app.NAME,
    RS2STRING('apc.UID_APPROVAL_PLAN', app.SUID,' distinct cln.CLIENT_NUMBER ', 'CLIENTS cln join APPROVAL_PLAN_CATEGORY apc on (cln.SUID = apc.UID_BILL_TO) ',', ') as BILL_TO_NUM,
    RS2STRING('apc.UID_APPROVAL_PLAN', app.SUID,' distinct cln.CLIENT_NUMBER ', 'CLIENTS cln join APPROVAL_PLAN_CATEGORY apc on (cln.SUID = apc.UID_SHIP_TO) ',', ') as SHIP_TO_NUM,
    app.LANGUAGES as LANGS,
    app.KEYWORDS as KEYWORDS,
    app.SHIPPING_METHOD as SHIP_METHOD,
    app.GEOS_COVERAGE as GEOS,
    app.INCLUDE_SHIPPING,
    app.DISCOUNT,
    nvl(app.BUDGET, 0::double precision) + nvl(app.BUDGET_KIEV, 0::double precision) + nvl(app.BUDGET_MPLS, 0::double precision) as BUDGET,
    app.BUDGET as BUDGET_MOSCOW,
    app.BUDGET_KIEV as BUDGET_KIEV,
    app.BUDGET_MPLS as BUDGET_MPLS,
    app.FISCAL_PERIOD_FROM as FISCAL_FROM,
    app.FISCAL_PERIOD_TO as FISCAL_TO,
    app.SHIP_PERIOD_FROM as SHIP_FROM,
    app.SHIP_PERIOD_TO as SHIP_TO,
    (select CURRENCY_SHORT_NAME from CURRENCIES where SUID = nvl(app.UID_CURRENCY, 'MS-CUR-USD')) as CURRENCY,
    app1.SUB_TOTAL,
    app1.SHIPPING_COST,
    app2.RETURNED,
    DECODE(app1.SUB_TOTAL, 0::double precision, 0::double precision, ROUND(NVL(app2.RETURNED, 0::double precision)/app1.SUB_TOTAL * 100)) as RETURNS_PERCENT,
    app1.QTY_TOTAL,
    ROUND(app1.SUB_TOTAL::numeric / app1.QTY_TOTAL::numeric, 2) as AVERAGE_BOOK_PRICE

    from APPROVAL_PLANS app,
    (select app.SUID as suid,
    sum(inv.QTY_TOTAL) as QTY_TOTAL,
    sum(inv.SUB_TOTAL) as SUB_TOTAL,
    sum(inv.SHIPPING_COST) as SHIPPING_COST
    from APPROVAL_PLANS app
    left outer join INVOICES inv on inv.INVOICE_DATE between app.FISCAL_PERIOD_FROM and app.FISCAL_PERIOD_TO
    and inv.UID_BILL_TO in (select apc.UID_BILL_TO from APPROVAL_PLAN_CATEGORY apc where apc.UID_APPROVAL_PLAN = app.SUID)
    and inv.UID_SHIP_TO in (select apc.UID_SHIP_TO from APPROVAL_PLAN_CATEGORY apc where apc.UID_APPROVAL_PLAN = app.SUID)
    and inv.INVOICE_STATUS = 'MS-INS-APPROVAL-PLANS'
    and inv.INVOICE_TYPE = 'MS-INT-INVOICE'
    and inv.uid_terms != 'MS-TRM-CANCELLED'
    group by app.SUID) app1,

    (select app.SUID as suid,
    abs(sum(fc.TOTAL)) as RETURNED,
    DECODE(sum(inv.SUB_TOTAL), 0::double precision, 0::double precision, ROUND(nvl(abs(sum(fc.TOTAL)), 0::double precision) / sum(inv.SUB_TOTAL) * 100)) as RETURNS_PERCENT
    from APPROVAL_PLANS app
    left outer join INVOICES inv on inv.UID_BILL_TO in (select apc.UID_BILL_TO from APPROVAL_PLAN_CATEGORY apc where apc.UID_APPROVAL_PLAN = app.SUID)
    and inv.UID_SHIP_TO in (select apc.UID_SHIP_TO from APPROVAL_PLAN_CATEGORY apc where apc.UID_APPROVAL_PLAN = app.SUID)
    and inv.INVOICE_STATUS = 'MS-INS-APPROVAL-PLANS'
    and inv.INVOICE_TYPE = 'MS-INT-INVOICE'
    and inv.uid_terms != 'MS-TRM-CANCELLED'
    left outer join FINCHANGES fc on fc.UID_OPERATION_TYPE = 'MS-FOT-RETURN'
    and fc.UID_INVOICE = inv.SUID
    and fc.DATE_OPERATION between app.FISCAL_PERIOD_FROM and app.FISCAL_PERIOD_TO
    group by app.SUID) app2

    where app.STATUS = 'MS-STS-0'
    and app.PROFILE_TYPE = 'MS-APT-APPROVAL'

    and app.SUID = app1.SUID(+)
    and app.SUID = app2.SUID(+)
```

Не могу понять как перенести в postgresql  app.SUID = app1.SUID(+) и app.SUID = app2.SUID(+)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1012622/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2-sql-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5

Answer (score -1):

неуверенно скажу так

```
FROM
    app
RIGHT JOIN app1 ON
    app.SUID = app1.SUID      -- (+)
RIGHT JOIN app2 ON
    app.SUID = app2.SUID  --(+)
```